# Accessing method in mapping block for tire/elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, elasticsearch, tire

I have a method that returns a hash:

```
def image_hash
  images = {
    small: 'http://www.example.com/image1.png',
    medium: 'http://www.example.com/image2.png'
  }
end
```

I need to index it as part of the ActiveModel mapping in Tire but I cannot get it to work with the `as:` option in the `indexes` method.

The problem is that I need to re-define it as images (which is another model method) so I'm trying it as so:

```
indexes :image_hash, as: :images do
  indexes :small, type: 'string', include_in_all: false
end
```

But the index is not being created properly.

I am aware of the `methods` option for the `to_indexed_json` method:

```
def to_indexed_json
  to_json( methods: [:image_hash] )
end
```

Which works. But I cannot see how to re-define it in that block without re-creating the entire JSON object from scratch. It also looks like the preference is to use the `mapping` block entirely for the indexed JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there but you can't dynamically get one item out of the hash if that's what you're trying to do

You probably want to use the type object so you can just store the entire has directly

```
indexes :image_hash, type: object, include_in_all: false
```

should be sufficient